# Register user with extra field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using devise I want to register a user with a type of plan, plan can be permanent or temporary. I have plans table where I have stored names of plans.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :plan
end
```

and in plan.rb I have

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :users
end
```

My first page consist two link to select this plan

```
= link_to "Register with Permanent Plan", new_user_registration_path
= link_to "Register with Temporary Plan", new_user_registration_path
```

How to pass this value of plan to next page so that when user sign up it will consist plan_id of respected plan? Help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!